# How to make predicate with dynamic where clause of SQL format

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have a requirement for the enterprise app that I'm working on where the SQL queries are stored in the system.

For example:

1. `WORKTYPE not in('PM','PM1','EV','OP')`
2. `:worktype <>'PM' AND :worktype <>'PM1' AND
   :worktype <>'EV' AND :worktype <>'OP'`

WORKTYPE n :worktype are the attributes of an entity

PM, PM1, EV and OP are the values to be filtered

=======================================================================

These are some of example where clauses that I have to handle in the NSPredicate.

Programming Language: Swift 4

Database: Coredata

Any suggestion of how to handle these expressions ?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. What problems are you having? Do you know how to create a simple `NSPredicate`? What about a compound predicate?

Comment: FYI - both example 1 and 2 are the same.

Comment: @rmaddy I wanted to do something like this NSPredicate(format: "WORKTYPE not in('PM','PM1','EV','OP')")

Comment: Yes both example 1 and 2 are same. These query where clauses can be written in any format which is unknown till I fetch

Comment: Have you investigated using [`NSExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression) to dynamically build predicates to match your queries?

Comment: No I have not @andrewbuilder. I will check with NSExpression.... any reference links ?

Comment: I’ll provide details in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can create NSPredicate at run time and at the end combine predicate using NSCompoundPredicate. Like in below syntax

```
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW - I agree with the comments - you should provide more information in your question and explain what you have tried, including attempts at code, etc... however failing that...

Read about the [`NSExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression) class, from the Apple Developer documentation...

> **NSExpression**
>
> An expression for use in a comparison predicate.
>
> **Overview**
>
> Comparison operations in an `NSPredicate` are based on two expressions, as represented by instances of the `NSExpression` class.
>   Expressions are created for constant values, key paths, and so on.

Although it is an archived document, Apple's "[Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html)" is still relevant to those using predicates with Core Data in both Swift and Objective-C. I recommend you read it.

Within this documentation, I specifically point you to...

[Creating Predicates > Creating Predicates Using Predicate Templates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-219639-BCIIHDCH)

The example from the documentation (translated to Swift)...

> The following example uses a format string to create a predicate with
>   a right-hand side that is a variable expression.

```
let predicateTemplate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName like[c] %@", argumentArray: [$LAST_NAME])
```

> This is equivalent to creating the variable expression directly as
>   shown in the following example.

```
let lhs = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "lastName"]
let rhs = NSExpression(forVariable: "LAST_NAME"]

let comparisonPredicate = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: lhs, 
                                                rightExpression: rhs, 
                                                modifier: .direct, 
                                                type: .like, 
                                                options: [.caseInsensitive])
```

So enough of the lecture and to your question...

> WORKTYPE not in('PM','PM1','EV','OP')

I assume here that you have the knowledge to parse your SQL expressions to extract the information set out in the first two lines of code below.

```
let keyPath: String = "WORKTYPE"
let arrayWorkTypes: [String] = ["PM", "PM1", "EV", "OP"]

var arrayComparisonPredicates = [NSPredicate]()

for workType in arrayWorkTypes {

    let expressionLHS = NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath)
    let expressionRHS = NSExpression(forConstantValue: workType)
    let comparisonPredicate = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: expressionLHS,
                                                    rightExpression: expressionRHS,
                                                    modifier: .direct,
                                                    type: .notEqualTo,
                                                    options: [.caseInsensitive])

     arrayComparisonPredicates.append(comparisonPredicate)
 }

 let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: arrayComparisonPredicates)
```

With your `andPredicate` built dynamically in this manner, you should be able to run your fetch request successfully.

I haven't tested this code so let me know how you go and I'll update if/when necessary.

And finally... your database is not Core Data.

If you’re using the Core Data framework in an Xcode project, your database is most likely [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Simply and according to Wikipedia, Core Data is “a model object graph and persistence framework...”

I highly recommend that you read and read and read some more until you truly understand the difference. I guarantee it will be a worthwhile investment of your time.